# How do I format a number in an "=CELL" type of statement?

Tags: microsoft-excel, libreoffice-calc, cell-format

I have a spreadsheet where cell A1 is `1234.56789`. In cell B1, I have `="$"&A1`. This shows up in B1 as `$1234.56789`. How do I make it show up as `$1,234.57` in B1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You need to do the followings:*

1. Select Cell `B1` and enter this formula `=A1`.
2. Click `Home Tab` and from `Numbers` category 
   pick & apply `Currency`format, keep `Decimal Place`, `2`.

**Or**

Apply this `$#,##0.00` as `Custom Format` on `B1`.

**Or**

Write this Formula in Cell `B1`.

```
=TEXT(A1,"$#,##0.00")
```

*You get `$1,234.57`.*

Comment: Glad to help you ,, keep asking ☺

Answer (score 4):

You're better off just copying/referencing the cell value (e.g. `=A1`) and changing the formatting of the cell to 'Accounting':

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Do what Glorfindel said, and also check if your system use "," as it thousands separators or not. Check it in Control panel > Region

To change the thousand separators in Excel, go to File > Options > Advance
 Deselect Use system separators. In the "Thoudands separators", type the character "," , then click OK.

[image]

Comment: If you go through `File, Option` & others then it will be applicable to entire workbook since  you are trying to change the `Default settings`. OP want to apply the specific format on Cell `B1` or may be on few cells!!